# tmpfs changes size on restart

Tags: mount, fstab, tmpfs

I have a tmpfs mount defined in my /etc/fstab with a size of 1024m, but when I restart the server it sizes itself to 5.9G.  If I run `mount -o remount /dev/shm`, the size will correct itself to 1G. But it'll revert the next time the server is restarted.

The entry in fstab is:

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   size=1024m        0 0
```

Could there another file that mount could be calling during startup?  How might I find that file?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care?  It's not as if that space is being used.

The default size is approximately half your system memory - and yes, there will be somewhere in your startup scripts that mounts a bunch of interesting tmpfs locations on a modern Linux.

You haven't said which particular distribution you use.  Various Debian derived distributions might control them via any of:

- /etc/init.d/mdadm-raid
- /etc/init.d/udev
- /etc/init.d/mtab.sh
- /etc/init.d/mountdevsubfs.sh

There's even a /etc/default/tmpfs on squeeze where you can set the default size.